# C2664 cannot convert * to ^

Tags: c#, c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am coding in windows 10 UWP with cocos2dx 3.8 and i want call a function in c++/cx with xaml from game sence( cocos2d ,c++).
and now
**Error C2664**

> “void
>   CocosAppWinRT::PayHelper::SetGetPay(CocosAppWinRT::OnStateChanged ^)”:
>   无法将参数 1 从“Platform::String ^(__cdecl CocosAppWinRT::OpenGLESPage::*
>   )(void)”转换为“CocosAppWinRT::OnStateChanged ^”.....

error pos:
m_helper->SetGetPay(&OpenGLESPage::GetOnPay);

code is there:

```
payhelper.h:
public delegate int OnStateChanged();
public ref class PayHelper sealed
{
public:
    PayHelper();
    int onPay()
    {
     if (m_getDelegate)
     {
        return m_getDelegate->Invoke();
     }
    };
    void SetGetPay(OnStateChanged^ del)
    {
        m_getDelegate = del;
    };
private:
    property static OnStateChanged^ m_getDelegate;
};

gamesence.h
CocosAppWinRT::PayHelper^ m_payHelper;
m_payHelper = ref new CocosAppWinRT::PayHelper();
m_payHelper->onPay();

OpenGLESPage.xaml.h
private:
    PayHelper^ m_helper=nullptr;
public:
    int GetOnPay();
cpp
m_helper = ref new PayHelper();
m_helper->SetGetPay(&OpenGLESPage::GetOnPay);

int OpenGLESPage::GetOnPay()
{
  return 8;
}
```

Comment: this seems more C++/CLI than C++

Comment: @jaggedSpire: It isn't C++/CLI. It is C++/CX, as explained in the question.